# Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '2016' for key 'PRIMARY' using Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried almost every answer available on this forum but nothing helped.

All my students have tracking IDs in this format: `2016-N-XXXX(any four digit number)`.

I have an "add student form" which is giving this error whenever I try to add a student with ID in this format.

My "create student" migration file is:

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
create_table :students do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "tracking_id"
  t.float "matric_percentage"
  t.integer "monthly_income"
  t.column "SEX", 'CHAR(1)'
  t.string "section" , index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.string "city"
  t.string "father_name"
  t.string "DOB"
  t.string "email"
  t.string "phone_number"
  t.string "secondary_phone_number"
  t.string "mailing_address"
  t.string "username"
  t.string "password_digest"
  t.timestamps null: false
end
end
def down
drop_table :students
  end
end
```

My model student.rb looks like:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :sections
has_secure_password
def self.authenticate(user,pass)
    student = Student.find_by_username(user)
    if student.authenticate(pass)
        return student[:id]
    else 
        return false
    end
end   
end
```

Here is my students_controller.rb (only relevant functions):

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end
  def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)
    @student.id=student_params[:tracking_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Student was successfully created.'
    format.html { redirect_to users_path(:admin => "students_view")}
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json {  render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit( :name, :tracking_id, :matric_percentage, :monthly_income, :SEX, :section,:city, :father_name, :DOB,  :email, :phone_number, :secondary_phone_number, :mailing_address, :username, :password)
end
```

Here is my form view:

```
        <%= bootstrap_form_for Student.new do |f| %>
      <%= f.errors_on :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, label: "Name", :required => true%>
      <%= f.text_field :tracking_id, label: 'NOP Tracking ID', :required => true %>
       <!--<%= f.text_field :section, label: "Section", :required => true %>-->
      <%= f.select :section, [["Select:", "?"],["Section A", "A"], ["Section B", "B"],["Section C", "C"],["Section D", "D"],["Section E", "E"],["Section F", "F"],["Section G", "G"], ["Section H", "H"], ["Section I", "I"], ["Section J", "J"], ["Section K", "K"], ["Section L", "L"]], { label: "Section" },{ class: "selectpicker" } %>
      <%= f.text_field :father_name, label: 'Father Name', :required => true %>
      <%= f.text_field :DOB, label: 'Date of Birth', :required => true, help: "Be Careful! Enter date in dd/mm/yyyy pattern only" %>
      <%= f.select :SEX,[["Select:", "?"],["Male", "M"], ["Female", "F"]],{ label: "Gender" },{ class: "selectpicker" }    %>
      <%= f.text_field :matric_percentage, label: "Matric Percentage", :required => true %>
      <%= f.number_field :monthly_income, label: "Monthly income", :required => true %>
      <%= f.text_field :city, label: 'City' %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, label: 'Email Address' %>
      <%= f.text_field :phone_number, label: 'Phone Number', :required => true %>
      <%= f.text_field :secondary_phone_number, label: 'Secondary Phone Number', :required => true %>
      <%= f.text_field :mailing_address, label: 'Mailing Address'  %>
      <%= f.text_field :username, label: 'Username', :required => true  %>
      <%= f.text_field :password, label: 'Password', :required => true  %>
      <div class="clearfix" type = "submit">
        <%= f.submit  %>
        <% end %>
```

And the complete error statement:

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '2016' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `students` (`name`, `tracking_id`, `matric_percentage`, `monthly_income`, `SEX`, `section`, `city`, `father_name`, `DOB`, `email`, `phone_number`, `secondary_phone_number`, `mailing_address`, `username`, `password_digest`, `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Sohail Aslam', '2016-N-7865', 344.0, 455, 'F', 'C', 'Lahore', 'Aslam', '25/12/1995', '17100283@lums.edu.pk', '+923229499463', '+923229499463', 'Lahore', 'student', '$2a$10$SZAV08mASBTM8oQr1.P.IOIKRD.Acn/F/VfBDI0DS2.n4cVuWO9B2', 2016, '2016-04-07 18:54:50', '2016-04-07 18:54:50')
```

Comment: put the view and  controller#create action code

Comment: added. could you please have a look now?

Comment: what is the need of @student.id=student_params[:tracking_id] ? you are already initialized this by passing students_param

Comment: Please add the error here

Comment: error statement added. checking that id thing

Comment: hey!! i commented that line and it started working.. thanks a lot Sir.. you are great.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is the line

```
@student.id=student_params[:tracking_id]
```

The `id` is not the same as `tracking_id`. While `id` is the Primary Key (PK) of your table (added automatically through the migration) 
`tracking_id` is an additional key that was added by you.

You should keep the standard PK and let the DB set its value (usually done through sequences).
Since you assign the tracking id that the user entered in the form to the `id` property, you are telling Rails that you take care of the PK. Because it is a String, it is converted to integer. See what happens when you convert "2016-1-1234" to int:

```
puts "2016-1-1234".to_i # => 2016
```

Now once you submitted the form there is a student with PK 2016 in the DB. And the next user is also assigned the same PK value. Hence the DB will complain, that there is already a row with the same PK.

Some remarks on your code:

- I'd keep the column names all lowercase (DOB, SEX). Just for consistency.
- SEX column can be created with t.string :sec, limit: 1
- You should add a unique index to your tracking_id: add_index(:students, :tracking_id, unique: true)
- You probably have created the controller from scaffold? Remove the respond_to, and format.json as well as format.html, the content of format.html block is actually enough (unless you have a JSON API)